# setting widths works correctly in chrome, but not firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome, rendering

I'm building a little pagination with jquery. I found a plugin that does some similar things (I'm still using my own). Both mine and this plugin: http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/ have a similar problem in firefox. If you view the "Demo 5" on that plugin's demo page, you can see the problem. In chrome it's perfectly fine. In firefox the last number wraps around to the next line.

Basically I have an `ul` with `li` elements in it. I need to add up all the `li` widths and set the `ul` width to that number. I need it to be precise (if you add more to the width, then the wrapping issue doesn't occur, but when you scroll to the end of the list of numbers, there's a bunch of space)

Any ideas why firefox is behaving this way?

I'm on mac osx by the way.

Comment: I don't see that with Firefox 4.0.1 in Win7.

Comment: @entropo, hmm maybe it's just a mac thing then? I edited my post to specify that.

Comment: Please don't write tags in question titles.

Comment: IE9 has this problem as well (interestingly enough, IE7 and 8 don't have it)... IE10 PP1 has it as well. odd.

Comment: IE9 and IE10 and Firefox 4 on Windows (as well as any version of Firefox that you'd still care about on Mac and I think on Linux) all do subpixel glyph positioning for text, so the width of a run of text ends up as a non-integer number of pixels.  Older GDI-based IE versions and WebKit-based browsers snap text to the pixel grid, so text runs end up with integer widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What method are you using to get the `<li>` widths?  If you're using jQuery's `width()` or `offsetWidth` or `clientWidth` then you'll get incorrect numbers, because all those round off non-integer widths.  The only things that will give you correct answers are computed style widths and `getBoundingClientRect().width`.

Chrome rounds widths to integers before doing layout, so the rounding methods don't do any more damage there (but as a result it can end up with seams around edges when the sum of the rounded widths doesn't actually end up to the width of the container).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue:
Jquery.paginate.js -> Just replace

```
_ul.css('width',insidewidth+'px'); [3rd line from last]
```

with

```
_ul.css('width',insidewidth+5+'px');
```

Its Solved.Working in FF,Crome,i.e 7,8,9
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the dev tools in IE and when i removed the `letter-spacing:2px` style on the body, it fixed it. Not sure if this will fix it for firefox, but it fixed it for IE9-10 and i'm guessing it's the same issue.